# Hadoop HDFS questions

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

For example, I have 2 datanodes and replication 2. When I do "hadoop dfs -put test.log input" that store a file into the HDFS, how is this file stored in the Hadoop Cluster? Is it spread over the whole cluster and stored on both two datanode servers?

Also, When I do some operation such as word count "hadoop -jar word count.jar input output", what does the whole process look like? The jobtracker will ask 2 task trackers to execute parallel and then store the output into HDFS?

Could I think that the first case is related to the namenode/datanode and the second case is related to the job tracker/task tracker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For example, I have 2 datanodes and replication 2. When I do "hadoop
> dfs -put test.log input" that store a file into the HDFS, how is this
> file stored in the Hadoop Cluster? Is it spread over the whole cluster
> and stored on both two datanode servers?

When you do hadoop **dfs -put test.log input** then the file **test.log** will get stored inside the directory called **input**. Here goes the flow,

Based on the **size of the file** and your **block size** the file will first get splitted into **n** small chunks, called as **blocks**. Default block size is **64MB**, but it is configurable. Now, with the help of NameNode the client will come to know which all DataNodes have free space to accommodate the data. Once this is done client will start pushing the data to the nearest DataNode block by block, which in turn will be pushed forward to other DataNodes based on your replication factor.

Yes, the file will be spread across both the machines. Remember Hadoop is a **distributed system** wherein **n** separate machines work collectively as a single system. See the diagrams shown below for a better understanding :

[image]

---

[image]

> Also, When I do some operation such as word count "hadoop -jar word
> count.jar input output", what does the whole process look like? The
> jobtracker will ask 2 task trackers to execute parallel and then store
> the output into HDFS?

The flow of a MapReduce execution goes like this,

You submit the job to JobTracker. The JobTracker directs the TaskTrackers(which run continuously) running on the machine where data to be processed is present to start the processing there itself without having to move the data anywhere. If the file you want to process is spread across n nodes then the TaskTrackers running on all those n nodes will start the processing in parallel. n is 2 in your case. See [this](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/459-anatomy-of-a-mapreduce-job-run-with-hadoop/) to know about the complete process.

> Could I think that the first case is related to the namenode/datanode
> and the second case is related to the job tracker/task tracker?

There is nothing to think about this. This is what that really happens :)

HTH

Comment: I still have a question about the first case. you said:

Comment: "client will start pushing the data to the nearest DataNode block by block, which in turn will be pushed forward to other DataNodes based on your replication factor." Based on my example, these two data nodes store the exactly the same info (like the nearest DataNode 1 store the data and the second DataNode 2 is the backup one)? What if the replication is 1, Hadoop will only store all the data into the nearest data node and the second one will not store anything?

Comment: Yes. If RF=1, data will be stored in only one node.

Comment: Oh, forgot one thing. "client will start pushing the data to the nearest DataNode block by block", for the client, the nearest DataNode will be always the same one, right? Does it mean that this data node will always store everything?